# Matrix groups with two generators

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups, lattices

Given two matrices $A,B\in{\rm{SL}}_2(\Bbb{R})$, is there any criterion guaranteeing that the subgroup they generate is discrete? What if one puts restrictions on $A,B$ e.g. they are both elliptic? What could the topological closure of $\langle A,B\rangle$ be if it is not discrete?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109967/algorithm-to-test-for-discrete-or-quasi-fuchsian-subgroups-of-psl2-c?rq=1 ?

Comment: Consider for instance the group generated by two upper triangular matrices with 1 one the diagonal, where the top right entry in the first matrix is 1 and in the second matrix is $\sqrt{2}$. The topological closure is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. You can do the same trick be taking diagonal matrices with $e^1, e^{-1}$ and $e^{\sqrt{2}}, e^{-\sqrt{2}}$ and similarly with rotation matrices (the topological closure will be the circle).

Comment: @darkl: These are "elementary" subgroups and usually are excluded from the discussion of discreteness algorithms. In many ways, they are quite different from the nonelementary subgroups for which algorithms work.

Comment: Here is a survey on this question: MR0974424 
Gehring, F. W.; Martin, G. J. 
Iteration theory and inequalities for Kleinian groups.
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 21 (1989), no. 1, 57–63.